# Can't Texture at some part and broken UV Map

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

This is my first time using Blender and then im trying to make a low poly girl model.
After its done, i try to unwrap the model with smart uv project, then go to the texture painting.
But the thing is, the paint is only working on the body. And i notice the UV Map is not complete as the UV Map when im unwrapping it. Any help?? (Sorry for the bad English)

[image]

Comment: hello could you please share your file?

Comment: Did you have the whole model selected ('A') in Edit mode before unwrapping?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: @moonboots okay its done

Comment: @JohnEason yes already did

Comment: Could you please share the link to your file?

Comment: it asks for an authorization   :(

Comment: That link requires you to allow access which is why it's best to use the official site at https://blend-exchange.com/ for blend file uploads following the instructions on that page. That assumes the file isn't over 30meg in size.

Comment: @JohnEason i've already try it but my file wont upload so i use gdrive instead

Comment: @Nevor Fair enough. I see you've now uploaded it again so problem sorted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you choose *Texture Slots > Mode > Single Images* instead of *Material*, make sure that you've selected the good texture (which is supposed to be *Sepatu* and not *Badan* if I judge by the image texture used by your material). Also select the object on which you want to paint (you can't paint on several objects at once). At last you need to make sure that the normals are correctly flipped, select all the objects, switch to *Edit* mode, select all the vertices and recalculate the normals (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>).

[image]